# Wind River Linux, Failed Dependency Error

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I am working on Wind River Linux. Failed Dependency Error. Can anyone please tell me what I have to do ? I have been trying from past one day

```
root@AC-04:/home/mysql# rpm -ivh MySQL-server-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm
warning: MySQL-server-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 5072e1f5
error: Failed dependencies:
        /sbin/chkconfig is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64
        /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64
        /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/debug is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64
```